# About QR code in Java and .net

Tags: android

I am working on Qr code and i am using it in "Mobile attendance system in android",Student come and scan qr code and student name,location,time etc goes to teacher through web services and teacher take attendance and save in

> ***database or cloud***

.
Can QR checks "WHO,when,from where "code scan........if this is fit project plz comment,if there is another application better than this,then please share with me,Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Have you try Zxing? Zxing contain libraries that you can use to create barcode or QRcode reader in android.
Here is the [link](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)

[Here](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/09/android-barcode-scanner-using-zxing.html) is the website that provide step by step how to use Zxing.

---

Addition

For your question about checking "who, when, where,...", I prefer that the students should log in first through their Android Apps (the account system should be build first), so we can track who scan it.

The QR code itself contain info such as, PLACE (where the QR placed), and TIME (only for double check, and it could be change monthly, weekly or any), and the info should be `ENCRYPTED`.

The reason that we should add time is because the students could save the QR picture and scan it anywhere, anytime (prevent from someone who cheat the system).

You could add other protection using their GPS data (but all those phone should have GPS). For example, using the GPS data to make sure that they scan the code in school area.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is no the worst idea for this kind of a system, so I'll give it a shot:

- What you can get from the QR image, is just an id. Then the app should check what is the place for this id, get the student name/surname and location from the app. Do **not** assume location of a person just because they used the tag.
- Your main concern will be forging. Since its a qr code, it is quite easy to duplicate, thus making the system highly tamperable. You could either swap these codes regularly, to make sure, that no-one has them yet, or use the location in the phone to only allow *check-ins* in some sort of an area. Take a look at Geofencing:https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

All in all, not a bad idea, but for the solution, I would also add in NFC tags, to make it a bit faster/secure.

Comment: Thanks janis,For checking Id etc the QR code is same or i use different QR code for different student,any other application in which i use qr code.

Comment: How QR code checks every student "ID"etc

Comment: The QR code can't check that. The QR code is just a simple text, that is encrypted, so that the device could "read" it more easily. What it usually contains in these cases, is just the class/course/teacher ID, and the indentification of a student is doen through the app. The student should have to authenticate upon launch of the app, inputing his/hers credentials.